# What is the recommended way to contribute editor menu

Tags: eclipse-rcp

When I read the Eclipse help, [there](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_actions.htm&cp=2_0_13_8) is an example of contributing menu using contributorClass. It's about actions a even retarget actions.
In addition there is a text:

> To understand how editors register themselves with the workbench and provide actions for the workbench menu bar, see the section discussing [org.eclipse.ui.editors](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_editors.htm). We won't rehash that information here.

the link leads you to a section where is nothing about contributorClass and even about actions, you have to use commands to contribute menus for editor they say.

Besides, in the Eclipse help is nothing about actions and retarget actions any more, since they are deprecated AFAIK.
I'm confused. What is the proper way of contributing menu for an editor? Why isn't the contributorClass deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the actions are deprecated for Eclipse 4.x(see [bug 285089](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=285089)) and you should use commands everywhere. The eclipse help isn't really helpful because it's not up to date. The [Vogella's Website](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html) has more accurate information and tutorials for the basic things you need in eclipse plugin development or eclipse rcp.